# QML - Imperative code not supported

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick-designer

Can someone comment on the fact that for `QML`, any imperative `JavaScript` code is not executed unless it is part of an [extra component](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2011/05/05/qt-quick-designer-in-qt-creator-2-2/). I am facing such kind of problem when I include the following code to my QML:

```
function qmlSlot(text){
    page.data=text
    if(page.data==="received")
        page.color="black";
}
```

As the Qt Designer get frozen and shows the following warning:

> Imperative code is not supported in the Qt Quick Designer

I read that building ***qmlpuppet*** installs an executable for rendering components in the `/bin` directory of the Qt building it. *Qt Quick Designer* checks for the Qt of the current project if a qmlpuppet is in the /bin directory. If yes it takes the qmlpuppet provided by the Qt version instead of the one provided by Qt Creator itself. In my case I haven't used the Qt static binary install, but instead built Qt from the source, thus [qmlpuppet](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/24394) executable was generated and is already located at:

```
/usr/local/Qt-5.2.1/qtcreator/bin
-rwxr-xr-x  1 qml2puppet
-rwxr-xr-x  1 qmlpuppet
```

So, the executable qmlpuppet is placed where is expected to be found and still this annoying message continues.

The workaround I took at moment is to comment out any so called "Imperative code" for when I want to edit the front-end QML using Qt Designer. Then after take out those comments to have the "Imperative code" activated again. But this is very annoying, although the code compile and works as I expected it to behave.

So, should I get worried about this warning? Anyway, there is some mean to get rid of this problem, as it froze the Qt Designer?

Comment: take a look at this http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/25270

Comment: @Apokal - thanks! I have added some extra info and link on that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is currently a reported QtCreator Bug :

<strike>https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-10940?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab</strike> 
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-10940

So don't be worried about the warning, it will be fix